# Problems with picture alignment in Microsoft Word - which other DTP software can I use?

Tags: software, book, graphics, microsoft-word

I have been struggling to write a book on my 14 years research. I have used Microsoft Word exclusively, but I have a problem that the book uses lots of pictures, sometimes six per page and this is where I cannot seem to have a stable document. I place the pictures in a Text Box as recommended by Microsoft. Having placed these text boxes relative to the text I find either that the pictures will not stay where they are placed or having closed the file and then re-opened the file, the text boxes are not in the correct place.

What DTP should I use as Microsoft Word does not seem to be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

It likely depends on the field you are in and the amount of work and money you want to put into learning a new tool if you have only used Microsoft Word so far for this kind of task.

For example in the technical and scientific community you normally find a lot of fans of [LaTex](https://www.latex-project.org/), which is free for anyone to use and offers incredible help with formulae. Have a quick look at the [Introduction to LaTex](https://www.latex-project.org/about/) to see if this is the kind of tool you need. If you need any help with it there is even a dedicated [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) sister site that can help you with all sorts of problems for example if you need help with the [Optimal arrangement of pictures/boxes in a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168748/154434). There is also a lot of other information out there, for example [Positioning images and tables](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_images_and_tables).

Another tool that you will see recommended on this site quite often is [Scrivener](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener/overview). I haven't used it so far, but apparently many writers often use it. It's a bit pricy though with [$45 for the full version](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/store/scrivener?tab=macOS) and there seems to be less information out there. For example by searching for [scrivener pictures is:q](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=scrivener+pictures+is%3Aq) I could only find this on Writing.SE: [How to work with in-text markup for figures and captions in Scrivener?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/5895/23159).

As you mentioned DTP, which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_publishing) often refers to software like [Adobe InDesign](https://www.adobe.com/de/products/indesign.html) (which is [really expensive](https://www.adobe.com/de/creativecloud/plans.html?single_app=indesign&promoid=19SCDS37&mv=other)) I want to say that you can find help for such professional layouting tools on our sister site [GraphicDesign.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), who even have a tag about [adobe-indesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign) who can help you with all sorts of [very specific image problems](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/37509/106597) in InDesign. I have never used this though, so take a look around the test version before thinking about buying and using this product.

Comment: Scrivener is a *word-processing* program. It is only for writing. It's not meant for layout.

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft Word, use tables instead of text boxes. The tables won't bounce around the page the way text boxes will. You can just create a one-row, one-column table to hold the picture and (if there is one) the caption. You can also make a table with six cells to hold six pictures.